# bash sqlite3 variable won't insert into database

Tags: bash, sqlite

I extracted the S/N of my devices with a script but I want to add those S/N into my SQLite3 database. Basically, I do an INSERT INTO database but the S/N variable is the only one not working. The field is always blank. I have other variables such as IP addresses or hostnames and they all work fine. The echos show the S/N properly, etc

Here is the test code:

```
Hostname="Test-Host"
IP="192.168.1.1"

SerialNumber=$(cat Log.txt | grep 'Serial Number' | sed 's/Serial Number: /\x0/g')
echo $SerialNumber

SerialNumber2="$SerialNumber"
echo $SerialNumber2

sqlite3 PsswdFileSQL.db  "insert into PsswdSQL (SN,Hostname,IP) values ('$SerialNumber2','$Hostname','$IP');"
```

I tried putting $SerialNumber in and it didn't work, so I thought I could try to "convert" the variable into a string by creating $SerialNumber2 and it didn't work neither. I'm out of options/idea.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the contents of `$SerialNumber2`?

Comment: Have you checked that the value matches the data type in table schema?

Comment: The content of $SerialNumber2 is the exact same as $SerialNumber which are both the S/N of the device.

Comment: The database has no datatype. I tried setting the variable like $Hostname with a fake S/N and it worked.